# An obelisk I pine

Tags: riddle

> An obelisk, I pine
>   
> My eye, some blood
>   
> Ink and horror
>   Farm stock food
>  is a labyrinth
>   
> Aid explorer

**Can you make sense of this?**

Comment: Is this really a riddle where the words have meaning, or more a cryptic clue / mnemonic kind of puzzle?

Comment: I imagine an old, decrepit, man in an asylum mumbling these things to himself....

Comment: @Khale_Kitha you probably guessed my true identity in that case! :P

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I'm afraid not, this is just a plain old riddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like @SQLnoob doesn't want to finish, I'll have a go.

You're a:

> Needle in a haystack (@SQLnoob)

An obelisk, I pine

> Cleopatra's Needle (or Brightling Needle) are obelisks. 
> Pine Needles (@SQLnoob)

My eye, some blood
Ink and horror

> eye of a needle, needle draws blood, ink could refer to tattoos which use a needle (@SQLnoob)

Farm stock food
is a labyrinth

> Hay (@SQLnoob)

Aid explorer

> A needle can be magnetized, and made to float in a bowl of water to create a simple compass.

Comment: This is correct so you get the accept, quick note that the 'farm stock food is a labyrinth' meant needle in a haystack, and then aid explorer was a different clue

Answer (score 12):

I can't make sense of all of it but could it be something like:

> Needle in the hay(stack)?

I'm getting that from:

> The first few lines could be construed as references to "needle" (an obelisk
>  is shaped like a needle, pine needles, eye of a needle, needle draws blood,
>  ink could refer to tattoos which use a needle, etc.)
>
>  "Farm stock food" could be hay?
>
>  Don't know about the last few lines, but something something "exploring" a
>  "labyrinth" might be like looking for a needle in a haystack?

Comment: Very nearly there, you got the answer, here's some clues - what's an obelisk called '_____ needle', pine is right, as is eye and the blood, and the ink. Needle in a haystack is right then the last line has to do with a map and compass (labyrinth part of the needle in haystack clue)

Comment: There are some famous obslisks called "Cleopatra's Needle". But I don't think I understand. Did SQLnoob solve your riddle or not? If yes, shouldn't you accept the answer? If not, what's missing other than what you've already revealed in your comment here?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan This answer is correct, it does not solve all hints though, so OP will probably wait for that to happen before he accepts the answer.

Comment: But it seems like the OP has already given explanations for all the hints not already explained in the answer.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, until full question is explained most OPs don't accept the answer. And I haven't solved the rest of the puzzle for the answerer, merely given hints

Comment: I don't even understand if I got the answer or not.  To be honest, I hate riddles, I just took a stab (no pun intended) at this one because I noticed all the needle references.  But I wasn't planning on continuing to work on it, if someone else wants to pick up where I left off they can post a full explanation and get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but some things I noticed.

> I think there's a few homophones at play here.
>  There's **I** and **eye**
>  "Farm stock food" would be **maize** which sounds like **maze**, which is a labyrinth